# UILabel changes color back on changing device orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicolor

I created a `UIViewController` in storyboard. There is a `UILabel` colored red. After some activity I change text on the label and it's `textColor` to green.

The strange thing is: when I change device orientation label's `textColor` changes back to red as it was at the beginning, but text stays.

How can I do that `textColor` on the label stays green after device rotation?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet private weak var volumeButton: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet private weak var clLabel: UILabel!

     override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
         if view.bounds.width < view.bounds.height {
             let traits = [UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact), UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .regular)]
             return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: traits)
         } else {
             let traits = [UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .regular), UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .compact)]
             return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: traits)
         }
     }

     @IBAction private func handleInputVolume(_ sender: UIButton) {
         coordinator?.inputData(type: .volume, delegate: self)
     }
}

 extension ViewController: InputDataReceivable {

     func didFinishInput(volume: Double) {
         volumeButton.setTitle(volume.formattedString, for: .normal)
         volumeButton.setTitleColor(.enabledGreen, for: .normal)
         clLabel.textColor = .enabledGreen
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Is your label is inside a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: Label is just in ViewController's view. Using autolayout in storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement viewDidLayoutSubviews method. ViewDidLayoutSubviews will be called

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts
>   the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    label.textColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it after calling the *self.view.layoutIfNeeded()* after change your label color. If its not work then use following code just change the label color programmatically again when your orientation change.

```html
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if(size.width > self.view.frame.size.width){
            //Landscape
            yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
        }
        else{
            //Portrait
           yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table is in tableView or collectionView
Then you'll need to implement your login in cellWillDisplay.

Comment: It's just label in ViewController. Nothing fancy

Comment: I added the code. What's happening that new controller opens there I insert some data into TextField and then via delegate it comes back and goes into button name and changes it's color and another clLabel color to green. then I turn ipad and color is back to red.